# Is it possible to associate Stack Overflow and LinkedIn accounts?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, linkedin

I would like to link from my LinkedIn profile to my Stack Overflow profile, and vice-versa. Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: If all you want to do is link from one to the other (as your question body suggests) you can surely link to your LinkedIn profile within your SO profile.

Comment: On SO profile, put link of your profile on LinkedIn and on LinkedIn put your SO profile link :)

Comment: Yes, I could put hyperlinks from one to the other, but was wondering if there was a specific field. Some other websites have a field that specifically asks for a link to the user's LinkedIn, Facebook, etc. account.

Comment: We don't. Stack Overflow is not a social network, nor do we want it to become one (nor a network site for professionals).

Comment: @ƉiamondǤeezeƦ: As far as specific fields, use the Website field in your SO profile to link to your LinkedIn profile and the Websites field in your LinkedIn contact info (Edit Profile > Edit Contact Info > Websites) to link to your SO profile.

Answer (score 6):

No, this is not possible.

Stack Exchange uses Open ID for authentication. LinkedIn uses their own system.

The two have no way to communicate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.  Communication per se is not necessary, just reciprocal hyperlinks in your SO and LinkedIn profiles.

As far as specific profile fields:

- Use the *Website* field in your SO profile to link to your LinkedIn profile.
- Use the *Websites* field in your LinkedIn contact info (*Edit Profile* > *Edit Contact Info* > *Websites*) to link to your SO profile.  (For help with the LinkedIn side, check out the LinkedIn Help Center article [Adding a Website to Your Profile](http://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3236).)

You can see below that I have done this with my SO and LinkedIn profiles.

***Figure 1:  Link in SO Profile to LinkedIn Profile***
[image: SO Profile Link to LinkedIn Profile]

***Figure 2:  Link in LinkedIn Profile to SO Profile***
[image: LinkedIn Profile Link to SO Profile]